# Z3: Fixed-size array of strings

Tags: z3

I would like to know how I can use type String and declare an array like

```
String status[3] = {"init", "phase1", "phase2"}.
```

I am trying to write an algorithm which has N processes and each process can be in the initial phase, phase 1 or phase 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z3 doesn't have string data-types. For the scenario you hint at, it seems unnecessary to have to represent the names of processors by strings. You might get away by simply creating separate variables for each process.